# Using the definition of differentiablity on several-variable function to prove the following fact is correct

Tags: real-analysis

We let $U$ open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $\vec a \in U$ and $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Assume that $f$ is differentiable at $\vec a$, for every $\epsilon > 0$ and $M > 0$ such that: there exists an $\vec x$ and $\vec y$, if $|\vec y - \vec a| < \epsilon$ and $|\vec x - \vec a|< \epsilon$, then $|f(\vec y)-f(\vec x)| \geq M|\vec y - \vec x|$. I first write down the definition of being differentiable at $\vec a$. I have $f(\vec a + \vec h) = f(\vec a) + \nabla f(\vec a)\cdot \vec h + E(\vec h)$, where $\frac{E(\vec h)}{|\vec h|}$ approaches $0$, when $\vec h \rightarrow \vec 0$. Then I put absolute value on both sides of the equation and get $|f(\vec a + \vec h)-f(\vec a)| = |\nabla f(\vec a) \cdot \vec h + E(\vec h)|$. Then according to the triangle inequality, $|\nabla f(\vec a) \cdot \vec h + E(\vec h)| \geq |\nabla f(\vec a) \cdot \vec h| - |E(\vec h)| $. Then also we can follow the definition from $\lim_{\vec h \to \vec 0} \frac{E(\vec h)}{|\vec h|} = 0$, we have for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that if $0 < |\vec h| < \delta$, then $|E(\vec h)|< \epsilon |\vec h|$. Then I'm confused what to do next to pick the $\vec y$ and $\vec x$ that we want. Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: What is the statement you’re trying to prove? If it’s the first statement, I have a feeling there’s some errors in it…

Comment: Yeah, it's the first statement.

Comment: A counterexample would be $f(x) = x$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Take $a=0$, $M=2$. Then for every $|x|,|y|<\epsilon$, we have $|f(x)-f(y)| = |x-y|$. But we don’t have $|x-y|\geq 2|x-y|$.

Comment: That is hard to prove as it is not true. Consider $f\equiv 1$ (constant function). Probably you want to assume that $Df(a) \neq 0$.

Comment: Pick some direction $v$ such that $\nabla f(a) \cdot v \neq 0$. Then consider $x=a+\varepsilon v, y = a -\varepsilon v$. Then we have by your argument $$ \vert f(x) - f(y) \vert = \vert f(x) - f(a) - (f(y)-f(a)) \vert = \vert \nabla f(a)\cdot (\varepsilon v) + E(\varepsilon v) - (\nabla f(a) \cdot (-\varepsilon v) + E(-\varepsilon v)) \vert = \vert 2\varepsilon \nabla f(a) \cdot v + E(\varepsilon v) - E(-\varepsilon v) \vert \geq 2\varepsilon \vert \nabla f(a) \cdot v \vert - \vert E(\varepsilon v) \vert - \vert E(-\varepsilon v) \vert. $$

Comment: If we choose $v= \nabla f(a) /\vert \nabla f(a) \vert$, then we have $$2\varepsilon \vert \nabla f(a) \cdot v \vert =2 \varepsilon =  \vert 2\varepsilon v \vert = \vert x - y \vert.$$

Comment: So the correct statement would be: Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open, nonempty set, $a\in U$ and $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable at $a$. If $\nabla f(a)\neq 0$, then there exists $M>0$ such that for all $\forall \varepsilon >0$ there exists $x,y\in U$ with $\vert x-a\vert<\varepsilon$ and $\vert y-a \vert <\varepsilon$ such that $\vert f(x) - f(y) \vert \geq M \vert x -y \vert$.

Comment: In essence what we are saying is that to leading order $f(x) \approx f(a) + \nabla f(a) \cdot (x-a) $, thus $f(x)-f(y) \approx \nabla f(a) \cdot (x-y)$.

Comment: But what about the 2 E terms you left over, since you only manipulate $2 \epsilon |\nabla f(\vec a) \cdot \vec v|$

Comment: If you wish to send me a comment you will need to write @SeverinSchraven (otherwise I will not be notified). The $E$ terms are small (compared to the gradient term, i.e. lower order), which you pointed out in your post. In as you argued, you can arrange it in such a way, that $\vert E(h) \vert \leq c \vert h \vert$ for any $c>0$ assuming that $\vert h \vert $ is sufficiently small. For example you could pick $c=1/4$, then my argument above shows that for $\varepsilon>0$ small enough, we get that $\vert f(x) - f(y) \vert \geq \vert x -y\vert/2$.

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake, it should be $$ 2\varepsilon \vert \nabla f(a) \cdot v \vert = 2\varepsilon \vert \nabla f(a) \vert = \vert \nabla f(a) \vert \cdot \vert x -y\vert. $$ So throw in a factor $\vert \nabla f(a) \vert$ everywhere.

Comment: Got you! Thank you so much! @Severin Schraven

Comment: @Miranda I suggest you try to write up your answer. That would help people in the future, gives the community to point out potential things you missed and (in case you care) helps you to gain some reputation :)

Comment: @ Severin Schraven  Yeah, thank you for your advice! I will do it!